# Why a simple set command becomes a slow query, Redis?

Tags: redis

When looking into the slow log, I find in one of my cluster, there are some slow queries which is set and expire command which even cost more than 60ms

Since the time is only the execution time which does not contain the queuing time and roudtrips time, so this means the command like

```
SET I2D_5b5e89403dc4e6580c0f4f45  a-24-length-string
```

My redis is totally 234GB and now 32GB is used. The command is sent to redis by JedisCluster.

Comment: What is the value you are setting? Maybe it is very large?

Comment: a 24-length string @Imaskar

Comment: That's a bit strange. Do you have RDB dumps or AOF set up?